# update_option using variable name

Tags: variables, options

Title may not be clear but I'm using `update_option($my_option, $new_order);` and for some reason it would not work but if instead I change to `update_option('my-option-name' $new_order);` it works.

I check that `$my_option` has a value and `'my-option-name'` exists and has some values on it.

Without digging more, is there any reason or cases where using a `$variable` may stop the update_option(), If so, how can be sorted.

Thanks

Comment: We need more code give an answer. The only reason is that `$variable` is either not set or has a wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$optionname = 'option_1';
update_option( 'prefix_' . $optionname, $option_value );
```

Answer (score 0):

it's posible only if your variable not exists at the moment of function update_option executes...

try to debug your application.

```
var_dump($variable,$data);
update_option($variable,$data);
```

Comment: That’s not how `var_dump()` works. The second argument controls the display option.

Comment: your right Toscho, too much console.log from yesterday... but anyway debuging update code is only way to ensure that we have a problem...